# Solving the integral $\int \ln\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right ) \frac{dx}{1-x^2}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, complex-integration, substitution

> I'm trying to solve the following indefinite integral:
>   $$I = \int \ln\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right ) \frac{dx}{1-x^2}$$

The integral is a general case which comes from a physics problem of potential in a capacitor with a rod inside.

I tried to figure out any plausible substitution or a transform by introducing a special function, but failed to do that.

- An approach I tried was by introducing a function:
  $h(z) = \mathrm{ln}|z| +i\phi$ for $0 < \phi < 2\pi$.
- An approach with a special function seemed applicable to the integral, such as the [Dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

**Update-1**:
Applying numerical integration from $0$ to $1$, I obtained (via Matlab, for self-check):

```
fun = @(x) log((1+sqrt(1-x.^2))./(1-sqrt(1-x.^2))).*(1./(1-x.^2))
q = integral(fun,0,1)
>> 4.9348
```

Which is $\frac{1}{2} \pi^2$.

Comment: [No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28%281%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%2F%281-sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29).

Comment: Thanks, right. However if we introduce integration bounds [0, 1], we obtain  $I_{0}^{1} = \frac{\pi^2}{2} $ [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28%281%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%2F%281-sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+1)

Comment: Where did this integral come from? And what are you really after (the definite/indefinite integral) ?

Comment: @Qubit it's common for antiderivatives not to have a nice form, but for certain definite integrals to have a nice form. If you'd be happy with a proof that $\int_0^1\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\frac12\pi^2$, edit your question to say that.

Comment: @Nyssa the integral comes from a physics problem of potential in a capacitor with a rod inside. This integral is a general case.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the correction. I'm trying to solve the integral as an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by using the substitution $x=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}$ then:$$I = \int \ln\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right ) \frac{dx}{1-x^2}=-4\int \frac{\ln z}{1-z^2}dz=2\int \frac{\ln z}{z-1}dz-2\int \frac{\ln z}{z+1}dz$$
$$=-2\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)-2\operatorname{Li}_2(-z)-2\ln z \ln(1+z)+C,\quad z=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x},x< |1|$$

---

The same substitution yields:

$$\int_0^1 \ln\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right ) \frac{dx}{1-x^2}=-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln z}{1-z^2}dz$$$$=-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 z^{2n}\ln zdz=4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2} $$

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Alternatively, the antiderivative's change between these limits simplifies to$$2(\operatorname{Li}_2(1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1))=2(\zeta(2)+\eta(2))=3\zeta(2)=\frac12\pi^2.$$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, yes. It's indeed a nice way to represent the function